# How to find the boundary of child Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to right align the Title on top of the last Div. As per the below image , the text should be on top of "Hello 5 / 4 / 3". When we resize the window button will float which is working and the text should be always be on top of the last button.

Unsure why the wrapper div is adding extra space to the right of the button and not aligning to the edge of the right most div. Extra space is coming even if the Title is not there , any insights about Div width calculation would be great.

I tried calculating the number of buttons in the top row using javascript and added offset to the title , but it seems tedious and not aligning at certain resolution.

http://jsbin.com/nonexegiqa/embed?html,css,console,output

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="title">Title</div>
   <div class="clear"/>
   <div class="btn">Hello 1</div>
   <div class="btn">Hello 2</div>
   <div class="btn">Hello 3</div>
   <div class="btn">Hello 4</div>
   <div class="btn">Hello 5</div>
   <div class="btn">Hello 6</div>
   <div class="clear"/>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .wrapper{
  border:solid gray 1px;
}
.btn{
  width:96px;
  height:46px;
  float:left;
  border:solid gray 1px;
  margin-left : 11px;
  margin-bottom : 11px;
  text-align:center;

}

.title{
  float:right;
}

.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to look some framework with responsive columns like bootstrap or foundation etc

Comment: You want to seting `title` on top of `hello 4`?

Comment: Im trying to get the Title should be on top on the last child Div. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find count of `.btn` in first row when page resizing, Then set position of `.title` to last `.btn` in first row.

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    var parWidth = $(".wrapper").innerWidth();
    var chiWidth = $(".wrapper .btn").first().outerWidth(true);

    var childCount = 0;
    while(parWidth >= chiWidth){
        parWidth -= chiWidth;
        childCount ++;
    }   
    var left = $(".btn:eq("+(childCount-1)+")").position().left;

    $(".title").css("margin-left", left);
});
```

To better understanding, i create demo but because you can't change demo page size in here, i create it in **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brf98q43/)**.

Comment: Great. Is there a way to achieve using CSS , just asking ?

Comment: @Anandh No, because when you resize page, last `.btn` changed and you need to find last `.btn`.

Comment: If we can make the parent Div flexible enough and adjust its width according to the childrens it will be possible right , could you please provide some insight on how DOM is calculating DIV sizing.

Answer (score 1):

yes, display:flex may be very helpful. As a work around you could set the width of the .wrapper to 70vw, or something similar. The .wrapper div width is creating the "extra space."